# String replacement in a column of dataset not working

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, string, numpy

Consider a data array as given below:

```
print((test_small_testval.features))
{'premise': Value(dtype='string', id=None), 
 'hypothesis': Value(dtype='string', id=None), 
 'label': ClassLabel(num_classes=3, 
                    names=['entailment', 'neutral', 'contradiction'], 
                    names_file=None, id=None)}
        
print(test_small_testval['hypothesis'][0:10])
        
['The owner threw the toy', 
 'The dog walked across the fallen log.', 
 'Woman eating pizza', 'The stove has nothing on it.', 
 'A girl is jumping off a bridge down into a river in a bungie cord.', 
 'The people are looking at a poster of Ronaldo', 
 'A man runs through a fountain.', 
 'The man is trying to get food for his family, as they are too poor to eat food from the supermarket.', 
 'The woman is asleep.', 'A room full of people is doing poses.']
```

When I use the following to do string replacement in the hypothesis column of the dataset, nothing happens. Not sure why.

```
for i in range(len(test_small_testval)):
print(test_small_testval['hypothesis'][i])
test_small_testval['hypothesis'][i] = test_small_testval['hypothesis'][i].replace('she','them')
test_small_testval['hypothesis'][i] = test_small_testval['hypothesis'][i].replace('he','them')
test_small_testval['hypothesis'][i] = test_small_testval['hypothesis'][i].replace('her','them')
test_small_testval['hypothesis'][i] = test_small_testval['hypothesis'][i].replace('him','them')
test_small_testval['hypothesis'][i] = test_small_testval['hypothesis'][i].replace('cat','animal')
test_small_testval['hypothesis'][i] = test_small_testval['hypothesis'][i].replace('dog','animal')
test_small_testval['hypothesis'][i] = test_small_testval['hypothesis'][i].replace('woman','them')
test_small_testval['hypothesis'][i] = test_small_testval['hypothesis'][i].replace('girl','them')
test_small_testval['hypothesis'][i] = test_small_testval['hypothesis'][i].replace('guitar','instrument')
test_small_testval['hypothesis'][i] = test_small_testval['hypothesis'][i].replace('field','outdoors')
print('>>>>after>>>')
print(test_small_testval['hypothesis'][i])
```

The data does not change at all. Can someone elaborate why?

What I am seeing:

```
The owner threw the toy
>>>>after>>>
The owner threw the toy
The dog walked across the fallen log.
>>>>after>>>
The dog walked across the fallen log.
Woman eating pizza
>>>>after>>>
Woman eating pizza
The stove has nothing on it.
>>>>after>>>
The stove has nothing on it.
A girl is jumping off a bridge down into a river in a bungie cord.
>>>>after>>>
A girl is jumping off a bridge down into a river in a bungie cord.
```

**Update:
I am able to do the replacement by saving to a new list altogether however, it is replacing substrings as well. Is there a quick way to replace only whole words and not substring appearances?**

regex approach:

```
import re

for i in range(len(test_small_testval)):
    #print(i)
    test_small_testval['hypothesis'][i] = re.sub(r'\bshe\b', r'them', test_small_testval['hypothesis'][i])
    test_small_testval['hypothesis'][i] = re.sub(r'\bhe\b', r'them', test_small_testval['hypothesis'][i])
    test_small_testval['hypothesis'][i] = re.sub(r'\bher\b', r'them', test_small_testval['hypothesis'][i])
    test_small_testval['hypothesis'][i] = re.sub(r'\bhim\b', r'them', test_small_testval['hypothesis'][i])
    print(test_small_testval['hypothesis'][i])
```

No change in output

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IGB4E.png)

Comment: What does `type(test_small_testval['hypothesis'])` show?

Comment: replace the r'\she\b' with r'\bshe\b' and so for others, you're not typing it properly

Comment: @JonClements. <class 'datasets.arrow_dataset.Dataset'>

Answer (score 0):

Your old strings will only be temporarily replaced with the new strings you've entered. You need to store it. This will do the job-

```
for i in range(len(test_small_testval)):
    print(i)
    test_small_testval['hypothesis'][i] = test_small_testval['hypothesis'][i].replace('she','them'
                                                                                    ).replace('he','them'
                                                                                    ).replace('her','them'
                                                                                    ).replace('him','them')
```

**Update 1:** I tested your sample (using a `list` of *strings*) and it worked. Maybe then the issue is with how you're accessing your array. I don't work with `numpy arrays` so you've to see that for yourself.

```
test_small_testval = ['The owner threw the toy', 
                        'The dog walked across the fallen log.', 
                        'Woman eating pizza', 'The stove has nothing on it.', 
                        'A girl is jumping off a bridge down into a river in a bungie cord.', 
                        'The people are looking at a poster of Ronaldo', 
                        'A man runs through a fountain.', 
                        'The man is trying to get food for his family, as they are too poor to eat food from the supermarket.', 
                        'The woman is asleep.', 'A room full of people is doing poses.']

for i in range(len(test_small_testval)):
    print(i)
    test_small_testval[i] = test_small_testval[i].replace('she','them'
                                                            ).replace('he','them'
                                                            ).replace('her','them'
                                                            ).replace('him','them')

print(test_small_testval)
```

Another issue that you're going to face after you resolve this is correct arguments for replacement.

> e.g., if I just replace 'he' with 'them' in 'The owner threw the toy',
> then you're going to get 'Tthem owner threw tthem toy' which I believe
> is not what you're intending.

One quick fix will be-

> considering that you're only replacing the members of the (she, he,
> her, him and they), one trick can be to replace 'she' with ' she' and
> likewise
> for all of them. this should handle almost all of your cases.

**Update 2:** Try this regex solution and see if it works (\b represents a word boundary)-

```
import re

for i in range(len(test_small_testval)):
    print(i)
    test_small_testval[i] = re.sub(r'\bshe\b', r'them', test_small_testval[i])
    test_small_testval[i] = re.sub(r'\bhe\b', r'them', test_small_testval[i])
    test_small_testval[i] = re.sub(r'\bher\b', r'them', test_small_testval[i])
    test_small_testval[i] = re.sub(r'\bhim\b', r'them', test_small_testval[i])

print(test_small_testval)
```

Comment: I did that but it still does not change.

Comment: Check out my updated question with the output I am seeing

Comment: I used a new list name and i see the changes but it is even replacing substrings. How do we replace only whole words?

Comment: i've added a quick fix in the answer, let me know if it works.

Comment: unless I choose a new name for the LHS list, it does not work. Further, I think only Regex might be able to correct replacement the way i want

Comment: True, regex is the way. i've updated the answer with a regex-based solution. let me know if it works or what cases are still needed to work upon.

Comment: that errors out

Comment: it works for me. did you import re module and are indexing properly?

Comment: Yeah fixed the error but the column does not get updated 

Checkout my updates to the post at the top @mrverma

Comment: it does work in list. for column you'll have to see where you're going wrong and fix your approach. once you fix that, this regex will do the job. good luck